# LFTP: SSH with private and public keys

Tags: command-line, ssh, sftp, public-key, private-key

I'm using LFTP in order to mirror SFTP server folder with local folder.

But currently I'd be glad to correctly connect to SFTP server and list contents...

I'm using Windows 7, and I've downloaded LFTP package from NWGAT (http://nwgat.ninja/lftp-for-windows/).

It is clear to me that I must first set up sftp connection by using `ssh` command:

```
ssh -v -a -x -vvv -o UserKnownHostsFile=/ssh/known_hosts -i /ssh/MyPrivateKey.ppk -p 22 user@sftp.domain.com
```

At the end of the post is the output of this command.

If I use WinSCP with the ppk file I'm able to connect without any problem. But using `ssh` in command prompt (with ppk does not accept passphrase, with pri authenticates) I'm getting this issue (the same issue happens when using putty with ppk file - server refused to start a shell/command).

Am I doing something wrong on my code or am I missing something?

Or should something be set also on server-side (ex.: permissions, something not matching)?

Here's the code and the output, thank you for your help.

```
ssh -v -a -x -vvv -o UserKnownHostsFile=/ssh/known_hosts -i /ssh/MyPrivateKey.pri -p 22 user@sftp.domain.com

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to sftp.domain.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/ssh/MyPrivateKey.pri" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /ssh/MyPrivateKey.pri type -1
debug1: identity file /ssh/MyPrivateKey.pri-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SFTP_XXXXX
debug1: no match: SFTP_XXXXX
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "sftp.domain.com" fr
om file "/ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-
rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-
sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hel
lman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh
.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v
01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@ope
nssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-ni
stp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour12
8,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,ae
s128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndae
l-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour12
8,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,ae
s128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndae
l-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,um
ac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hma
c-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-1
28@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh
.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,um
ac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hma
c-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-1
28@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh
.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha
1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-sha2-256@attachmate.com,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha512,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha2-256,h
mac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha512,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha2-256,h
mac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4119/8192
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 45:49:72:ff:5c:97:0b:ba:57:98:5a:2a:49:18:21:fa
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "sftp.domain.com" fr
om file "/ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" from file "/ssh
/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'sftp.domain.com' is known and matches the RSA host key
.
debug1: Found key in /ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 4092/8192
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /ssh/MyPrivateKey.pri (0x0), explicit
debug3: input_userauth_banner
****************************************
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
****************************************
This system is for the use of authorized users only
****************************************debug1: Authentications that can continu
e: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /ssh/MyPrivateKey.pri
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/ssh/MyPrivateKey.pri':
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to sftp.domain.com ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 16384 rmax 35000
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSH toolset does not understand the `.ppk` key file format. It uses its own format. Just as PuTTY (and WinSCP) uses its format (the `.ppk`) and so does not understand the OpenSSH format.

You can use the PuTTYgen (from PuTTY toolset) to convert the `.ppk` key to the OpenSSH format.
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-conversions

Answer (score 0):

This is the same behavior as sftp  (ssh does not know about ppk format), you need to convert your ppk file to openssh format.

I used this procedure to convert my ppk from a windows (winscp script) to a linux (sftp script).

From the windows application :

- open puttygen ,clic load
- select your ppk and type your passphrase as prompted
- clic conversion menu -> Export OpenSSH key
- choose a new filename.key and clic save

**note** :  the new ssh key keeps the passphrase in the conversion process

to test the key
secure your key file first : `chmod 600 yournewsshkey.key`

```
sftp -v -i yournewsshkey.key user@ftpsite.url
```

When prompted , type your passphrase

Cheers